# how to modify app content when app is on server(after building)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, deployment

I just deployed a website but I want to mutate its content , should I resend the build folder to api or I should change something in the code?

Comment: Yes, you need to redeploy the build.

Comment: You can use a cms if you have text. For javascript you need to redeploy with updated code.